# Getting error bean with name creating bean org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

I am using Spring 4.3 and hibernate 3.6.7 in my project when I run the test cases I am getting the error as below. Can some one explain me where I need to change in the code.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerHibernate' defined in class path resource [com/ikam/rix/test/BaseIntegrationUnitTestCaseContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

applicationContext.xml: Please find below applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="transactionManagerHibernate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryTest" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTest" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSourceTest" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ****-lx2217.ikamdt.com)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ****.ikamDT.COM)))" />
        <property name="username" value="**" />
        <property name="password" value="**" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="systemParameters" class="com.ikam.rix.common.config.facade.impl.DefaultSystemParameters" />
    <bean id="batchKeyGenerator" class="com.ikam.rix.common.batch.pub.impl.DefaultBatchKeyGenerator" />
    <bean id="batchPostProcessor" class="com.ikam.rix.common.batch.pub.impl.DefaultBatchPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="batchQueuer" class="com.ikam.rix.common.batch.pub.impl.DefaultBatchQueuer" />
    <bean id="batchLogger" class="com.ikam.rix.common.batch.pub.impl.DefaultBatchLogger" />
    <bean id="batchConfiguration" class="com.ikam.rix.common.batch.pub.impl.DefaultBatchConfigurationImpl" />
    <bean id="dataIntegrationKeyGenerator" class="com.ikam.rix.common.dataintegration.impl.DefaultDataIntegrationKeyGenerator" />
    <bean id="subscriptionKeyGenerator" class="com.ikam.rix.common.subscription.SubscriptionKeyGeneratorTestImpl" />
    <bean id="idrsJobKeyGenerator" class="com.ikam.rix.common.idrs.IdrsJobKeyGeneratorTestImpl" />
    <bean id="configParameterCache" class="com.ikam.rix.common.config.cache.impl.DefaultConfigParameterCache" />
    <bean id="sessionFactoryTest" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTest" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Look here: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry

Comment: Are you sure the xml which you have post is `pom.xml`?

Comment: it is applicationContext.xml my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like class org.hibernate.service is not found in the WEB-INF\lib folder. may be you miss out `hibernate-core`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```